# How to enable or disable specific textboxes according to the selected option

Tags: html, css

When I select `Lock` from the menu, i want to disable all text fields in that row except the first text field to prevent any text input. When I select `Unlock` Allow text entry in all fields.

HTML

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Not Lock</td>
    <td>Lock/Unlock</td>
    <td>Lock/Unlock</td>
    <td>Lock/Unlock</td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><select name="select" id="select">
          <option value="0"></option>
          <option value="1" selected>Lock</option>
          <option value="2">Unlock</option>
        </select></td>
        <td><input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" value="1"  /></td>
        <td><input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" value="1" /></td>
        <td><input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" value="1"  /></td>
        <td><input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" value="1"  /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><select name="select" id="select">
          <option value="0"></option>
          <option value="1" selected>Lock</option>
          <option value="2">Unlock</option>
        </select></td>
        <td><input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" value="1"  /></td>
        <td><input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" value="1" /></td>
        <td><input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" value="1"  /></td>
        <td><input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" value="1"  /></td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Looks like you missed the <table> tag due to formatting issues. I've edited the title and description to helps future readers... Feel free to update the question is anything is wrong. Hope the answer helps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/e8nS7/2

Added a `div` on top with `class="row"`

Changed textboxes `ID` to `class` since all of them are using it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.row').each(function () {
        var $dropdown = $(this).find('#select'),
            $textfield = $(this).find('.textfield');
        $dropdown.change(function () {
            if ($dropdown.val() != '1') {
                $textfield.removeAttr('disabled');
            } else {
                $textfield.attr('disabled', 'disabled').val('');
            }
        }).trigger('change'); // added trigger to calculate initial state
    });
});
```

Comment: any particuloar reason for copy pasting [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24354208/2333214)..?

Comment: example > add rows not works demo http://jsfiddle.net/ahmetsadri/SDctG/

Answer (score 1):

If using jquery is not an issue

```
$('select').change(function () {
 if ($(this).val() == '1') {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input:not(:first)').attr('disabled', 'disabled').val('');
 } else if ($(this).val() != '1') {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input').removeAttr('disabled');
 }
}).trigger('change');
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e8nS7/3/)